# HashMap says Key doesn't exist even though it does

Tags: java, hashmap

I have run into an interesting problem which I'm pretty sure is the fault of `HashMap`. Consider the following debug code (AMap is a HashMap, key is a value passed to this method)

```
System.out.println("getBValues - Given: " + key);
System.out.println("getBValues - Contains Key: " + AMap.containsKey(key));
System.out.println("getBValues - Value: " + AMap.get(key));
for(Map.Entry<A,HashSet<B>> entry : AMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("getBValues(key) - Equal: " + (key.equals(entry.getKey())));
    System.out.println("getBValues(key) - HashCode Equal: "+(key.hashCode() == entry.getKey().hashCode()));
    System.out.println("getBValues(key) - Key: " + entry.getKey());
    System.out.println("getBValues(key) - Value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Now in this Map I insert a single key (Channel) and value. Later I try and get the value back with `get()` and run this debug code which in my case gives this output:

```
getBValues - Given: Channel(...)
getBValues - Contains Key: false <--- Doesnt contain key?!
getBValues - Value: null   <--- Null (bad)
getBValues(key) - Equal: true <--- Given key and AMap key is equal
getBValues(key) - HashCode Equal: true
getBValues(key) - Key: Channel(Same...)
getBValues(key) - Value: []    <--- Not null (This is the expected result)
```

As you can see, fetching the key from the HashMap directly doesn't work but looping through I get the exact same key, meaning its there it just can't be found with `get()`. My question is what would cause this? How can `get()` not find a key that exists?

I would provide an some example code of this but I can't seem to reproduce this independently.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Comment: *"... which I'm pretty sure is the fault of HashMap"*.  Repeat after me. "The bug is in **my** code." - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-programming/1842#1842

Comment: @Stephen I was meaning it more as "Some 'feature' in HashMap is causing this"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, we still haven't ruled out if it has to do with immutability.
If you do:

```
aMap.put(key, value);
key.setFieldIncludedInHashCodeAndEquals(25);
```

then you would get the result from above.

To rule this out, either show us more of your code or, in the for loop in your example above, add

```
System.out.println(aMap.get(entry.getKey()));
```

Also, use a debugger. That way, you can see if your object is in the correct bucket.

Comment: Hmm... that gave me a null value. I guess the hashCode is changing after its been added. I'll see if I can update my code to something workable.

Comment: So, did any field, being part of hashCode or equals in the object you stored as key in aMap, change after you added the object to your map?

Comment: This is why keys in maps have to be immutable.

Answer (score 8):

I'll bet you didn't override equals and hashCode properly in your key Channel class.  That would explain it.

Joshua Bloch tells you how to do it correctly in his "Effective Java" Chapter 3.

http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf

Comment: I did with Project Lombok, even specifically excluding 2 HashSets in the class which would affect equality.

Comment: I don't know what Project Lombok is; I can't tell if that means "yes, I have a proper equals and hashCode implemented."  Best if keys are immutable, too.  Is that true for your channel?

Comment: In his particular test hashCode gives same value for key and stored key. It may be implemented incorrectly or correctly, but this instance has it right. key.equals(entry.key) also gives true. the only remaining cause I can see if entry.key.equals(key) is false.

Comment: Sorry, thats a yes. Hashcode is implemented correctly. Look here http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html

Comment: +1 THAT was it! I didn't override hashCode in my code and it caused keys to not work as expected. Thank you so much xD !

Comment: Overriding hashCode did a trick for me. Coz I overrided only equals before, but you should override both to make it work. Thanks